# spark scala dataframe.show is getting stuck

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am running simple spark code on EC2 instance. It writes dataframe with 6 records and 6 columns as parquet file and then tries to read it and display content. It is getting stuck on `df.show()` step. Data is not huge or anything.

code to read is

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://path")
df.show()
```

If I write and read as csv then I am able to display.

Comment: no reason why that shouldn't work. have you tried any other operations on the data frame? e.g. `df.count()` or in particular `df.printSchema()` which may indicate whether there is a problem with the underlying file

Comment: yes @Chris I tried df.count() and it works. it gives correct count as 6. Also looping thru columns using df.schema.fields and printing column names works

Comment: df.printschema() also works fine and no issue with schema too

Comment: Not come across this issue before sorry. Any luck just showing limited number of rows? e.g. `df.count(n=1)` I might also try to convert to Pandas and then display the data using Pandas to see if there is a similar issue e.g. `pdf.head()`

Comment: i have scala code.  and df.show(2) also does not work.